# How do you create a list of lists using a 'for' loop with input(s)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create lists/ records using the input function and 'for' loops, but I can't seem to get more than one list to populate. Ideally, I like to be able to define the number of sub-lists I want to create and then input the information per list until the total number of specified lists has been created.

```
def new_row(n):
    for i in n:
        y = []
        month = input('Enter the month: ')
        city = input('Enter the city: ')
        numCoups = input('Enter the number of coupons accepted: ')
        numAds = input('Enter the number of advertisments ran: ')
        l = [month, city, numCoups, numAds]
        y.append(l)

new_row(input('How many entries do you wish to input'))
```

Comment: You're creating the list _inside the loop_.

Comment: as jon says, move y = [] outside of the for loop then it won't be recreated empty every time

Answer (score 2):

```py
def new_row(n):
    y=[] #outside the loop
    for i in range(n)#range function:
        month = input('Enter the month: ')
        city = input('Enter the city: ')
        numCoups = input('Enter the number of coupons accepted: ')
        numAds = input('Enter the number of advertisments ran: ')
        l = [month, city, numCoups, numAds]
        y.append(l)
    new_row(int(input('How many entries do you wish to input'))) #int function
```

You should declare the list outside the loop and you should convert the input to an integer, because by default it's a string,you should use range func in for loop

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think the line where you call `new_row()` is indented too much, and your range loop needs a colon(:).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the initial list outside the for loop and you need to convert the input to an integer and use range(n) instead of n:

```
def new_row(n):
    y = []
    for i in range(int(n)):
        month = input('Enter the month: ')
        city = input('Enter the city: ')
        numCoups = input('Enter the number of coupons accepted: ')
        numAds = input('Enter the number of advertisments ran: ')
        l = [month, city, numCoups, numAds]
        y.append(l)
    return y

new_row(input('How many entries do you wish to input'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def new_row(n):
    y = [] # outside the loop, otherwise it keeps on getting reset
    for i in range(n): # or [for i in range(int(n)):], if n is a string
        month = input('Enter the month: ')
        city = input('Enter the city: ')
        numCoups = input('Enter the number of coupons accepted: ')
        numAds = input('Enter the number of advertisments ran: ')
        l = [month, city, numCoups, numAds]
        y.append(l)

new_row(int(input('How many entries do you wish to input')))
        #you need to do int(input()) because input normally returns a string, but you want a number
```

Answer (score -1):

if n is a number you should change n to range(n)
it's unclear n, also you have to let y grow by lefting it outside the loop because it will always be dscarded, finally you must return the value of y because if you don't do this you are also discarding it, maybe you can pass it as a parameter if you want to reuse it. For Example:

```
def new_row(n, y=[]):
    for i in range(n):
        month = input('Enter the month: ')
        city = input('Enter the city: ')
        numCoups = input('Enter the number of coupons accepted: ')
        numAds = input('Enter the number of advertisments ran: ')
        l = [month, city, numCoups, numAds]
        y.append(l)
    return y

result_rows=new_row(input('How many entries do you wish to input'))
```